# Free webfont similar to Impressum Std Roman

Tags: web-fonts, font-recommendation, free

I am looking for a free web font which is as similar as possible to [Impressum Std. Roman](https://store1.adobe.com/cfusion/store/html/index.cfm?store=OLS-US&event=displayFont&code=IMPQ10005000), I've used it extensively in a design, but now it's come to developing the web page, I am looking for an alternative as there doesn't exist a free web font version.

I know that it's foolish of my to have used it in my design without checking the web font availability but I will be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Three free alternatives are, for instance …

### Lora (by Cyreal)

http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Lora

### Playfair Display (by Claus Eggers Sørensen)

http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Playfair+Display

### Domine (by Impallari Type)

http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Domine